# How to convert "Convert.ToUInt32(char value)" of C# to Java

Tags: java, c#

I need to convert **Convert.ToUInt32(char value)** code to java. this function return uint value in C# same implementation i need for java.

I have done bit google work but didnt get expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't have a type equivalent to UInt. The C# function `Convert.ToUInt32(char value)` converts the Unicode value of its argument to a `UInt32`. The closest you can get to that in Java is `(int) value`. This will give you the value converted from `char` to `int` and will always be a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **(int) char value**

Comment: It's not `Character.getNumericValue` - that returns 0 for '0', but what the OP wants is to return 48 (the Unicode value) for '0'. That's done with `(int) char value`.

Comment: hi @k314159 , (int)char value, will work for me. but i need result in uint, uint is basically unsigned integer which has a range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: @SurajVerma unfortunately there is no such thing as a uint in Java.

Comment: Why do you think you need an unsigned int?

Comment: @k314159 look like there is no such thing uint in java, so im goint with "(int) char value"

Comment: @k31459 apologies for this mistake, I have edited my answer to only include the type cast to int.